# Selling a college house

Tags: real-estate

Let's say a father buys a moderately decent house for his daughter to live in for college. 4 years later he sells for a profit. Would capital gains taxes come into play given that the house is his daughters primary residence, but not his?

Answer (score 3):

> Would capital gains taxes come into play given that the house is his daughters primary residence, but not his?

Yes. He sold something that was his property, i.e., his [long term] asset. The fact that it was not his primary residence is irrelevant in this regard.

The issue of primary vs. non-primary residence might be relevant only for purposes of computing the applicable credits and/or deductions, but that is very jurisdiction-specific.